# What can be done about the Syncfusion tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation, outsourcing

The problem with [syncfusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syncfusion) is that employees of this company treat Stack Overflow like a ticketing system. This leads to a number of issues:

- Too many greetings and salutations [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66816190/1)
- Answers asking for more clarity [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67313095/1839439)
- Answers with only links to help pages [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64371206/1839439)
- Answers linking to full demos/solutions on Stack Blitz [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229933/1839439)
- Answers locked in inaccessible zip files [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65287069/1839439)
- Noisy answers that in summary say "we can't reproduce this issue" [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67330224/1839439) [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708404/1839439)
- Bug reports posted as questions [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67412662/1839439)
- Feature requests posted as questions and getting responses as answers [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66747642/1839439)

One user suggested that having the tag itself is a problem as their products should be disambiguated with each having its own tag.

I would suggest sending them a polite email asking them to stop this kind of behaviour, but I am afraid this might have no effect at all.

Comment: It may have no effect at all. But I see no harm in trying it out.

Comment: For now, I'll comment on posts with taglines: `Here on Stack Overflow, pages are primarily meant to be useful to future readers. Because of that, "taglines" like "Hi" and "Thanks" are discouraged.`

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE don't add more noise doing that :) Just edit these things out and move on, they are unlikely to change without company's involvement.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE That should be your *edit summary* when you make an edit removing these taglines/signatures/salutations. Could even include a link to the Help Center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior. But please, as Oleg said, don't just leave that as a comment.

Comment: I feel the employees' behavior and not the tag is the problem. That can only be changed if the people doing that are notified.

Comment: Easily solved: Have them purchase a Collective(tm), then no one can tell them what to do! /s

Answer (score -18):

You could try emailing them, or leaving a comment on some of the problem question/answers, both giving them a link to this post. However for the questions, it is other people posting them, so that behaviour is unlikely to change, so then all you can do is below.

- Too many greetings and salutations => Edit out
- Answers asking for more clarity => Downvote/Flag as not an answer
- Answers with only links to help pages => Downvote/Flag as not an answer
- Answers linking to full demos/solutions on Stack Blitz => If only a link, Downvote/flag as not an answer.  If it does contain a solution, vote accordingly.
- Answers locked in inaccessible zip files => If the answer doesn't stand up on it's own without that file, Downvote/flag as not an answer
- Noisy answers that in summary say "we can't reproduce this issue" => Probably flag as not an answer.
- Bug reports posted as questions => If not a quality question, downvote.  If off topic, vote to close.
- Feature requests posted as questions and getting responses as answers => Vote to close.

Comment: The question is about the behaviour from Syncfusion employees. It should be corrected at the root, as it's the company that sends them to SO with instructions to post these (or without instructions to not post these, if you wish). They are forcing their *paid* employees to cause more work for the *unpaid* volunteers.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I understand that, but trying to change others behaviour is always difficult.  If enough people above do the above actions, maybe they will realise what they are doing is a problem.

Comment: Usually, these would be the recommended actions, but if they were enough I would have no reason to make this post. This doesn't really work. They might get a hint, but not all of them. The problem is how to provide all of them with guidance so that they can follow Stack Overflow quality guidances.

Comment: Having worked on helpdesks, the turnover at places like that is too great for people to "get the message".